# Conditional use of "if" in past tense

Tags: if

I found a sentence that says, "If any man were lurking in dark, we would know it."
Should we use 'if any man were'? Or should we write "If any men were...."?

Answer (score 1):

The use of *were* is nothing to do with the number of hypothetical men, it is the subjunctive, used in conditional sentences in formal grammar. https://writersrelief.com/2008/03/16/was-versus-were-and-other-examples-of-the-subjunctive-mood/

I would expect 'in *the* dark', though.

Comment: Thank you Kate! You've been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The use of **any** in a  sentence depends on the context.

If the word refers to **a total number of something**, it is used with *plural and uncountable nouns*. For instance,

> Let us know if your bag contains any scissors or knives.

But if the word is used for **any of kind**, it can be used with *singular and uncountable nouns*. For instance,

> If any man were lurking in dark, we would know it.

Source: [BBC World Service](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv303.shtml)

Comment: Thank you so much! You've been very helpful!

Answer (score -3):

"If any men were lurking" sounds wrong. You should use the singular.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with _if any men were_ if you mean the plural.

Comment: Can you bring evidence that it's wrong?

Comment: Thank you Riolku!